# Schema.org 'name' and 'headline'

Tags: schema.org

In Schema.org, I do not understand the difference between `name` and `headline`. I try to apply it to a page that there is only a blog post. In this case, what would be the name and the headline?

I tried the Google tool google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/ and I selected the `h1` of the post as the `name`.

Then I go to the testing tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool and it gives me an error in red:

> A value for the headline field is required

So, it seems that I can not ignore one of them.

What is the `name` and `headline` in a blog post?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="entrada">

<img itemprop="image" class="imatge" src="../externs/img/1.png">
<h1 itemprop="name" class="titol_post">Title of the post</h1>
<div itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-07" class="data"></div>

<div itemprop="articleBody" class="text">       
    <p>This is the body of the post</p>
</div>

<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><h2 itemprop="name">NM.</h2></span>

</div><!-- end esquema Article -->
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use both properties (`headline` and `name`) for the same content.

```html
<h1 itemprop="headline name">Title of the post</h1>
```

Google requires `headline` for their [Articles search feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) (and it doesn’t seem to use `name` for anything else). If you don’t care about this feature, you could of course ignore the error.

My related answers on Stack Overflow:

- [to the question *News item in Schema.org*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932165/1591669)
- [to the question *What is the name property in schema.org?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38001407/1591669)

Comment: A similar question is when the author and the publisher is the same. Like in my blog. should I use itemprop="author publisher"  ?

Comment: @Nrc: Yes. Note that using multiple properties in the same `itemprop` attribute is, semantically, the same as if using multiple elements (each with its own `itemprop`), repeating the value. -- So whenever two or more properties (of the same entity) would have the same value, you can use them together in one `itemprop`.